# Middleware is not updating location in Next.Js

Tags: next.js, middleware

so I am trying to do redirection in middleware it's working fine but it's not updating
Browserlocation

code:

```
export function middleware(req, ev) {
  if (signedinPages.find((url) => url === req.nextUrl.pathname)) {
    console.log("cookies", req.cookies);
    if (!req.cookies.token) {
      const url = req.nextUrl.clone();
      url.pathname = "/Login";
      return NextResponse.rewrite(url);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Rewrite will not change the browser's URL. What you want is a redirect.

Comment: Yes redirect() work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

working with this code

```
export function middleware(req, ev) {
  if (signedinPages.find((url) => url === req.nextUrl.pathname)) {
    if (!req.cookies.token) {
      const url = req.nextUrl.clone();
      console.log(url)
      url.pathname = "/Login";
      url.search = "";
      return NextResponse.redirect(url);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

**in earlier version of nextjs or lets say @latest , _middleware is no longer working, please try to add /middleware.js outside pages
and it will work fine**

[image]

Comment: For me middleware at top is not triggering for subroutes, any idea why?

Comment: what version of nextjs are u using ?